# Is it possible to get file path from windows photo viewer

Tags: c#, registerhotkey, photoviewer

I want to get the file path of a photo from the windows photo viewer with RegisterHotKey. I know how to use RegisterHotKey, but I don't know how to code into the method to get the file path of a photo from windows photo viewer.